# How to implement a Two-Sample McNemar Test in R

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, mcnemar-test

I'm trying to perform a Two-sample McNemar's test on my data, but I was not able two find any R package implementing the method. I'm familiar with the simple McNemar's test function mcnemar.test(), but it's not sufficient for what I'm trying to do.

The Two-sample version of the test is described here : Feuer, Eric J., and Larry G. Kessler. “Test Statistic and Sample Size for a Two-Sample McNemar Test.” Biometrics, vol. 45, no. 2, 1989, pp. 629–36. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2531505.

I tried to understand the paper to write my own implementation of the test in R, but this is a bit beyond my math skills.

Does anyone know a package implementing the test or know how to do it?

Comment: As I write this comment, JSTOR is having technical difficulties.  The following is a link to the paper on PubMed: [https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2765642/](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2765642/).

Comment: It sounds like the paper described in the question works for situations with a binary outcome.  In that case, a mixed-effects logistic regression model should be able to handle this situation.  Perhaps there is an example in the paper that can be replicated with this approach.

Comment: See also: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595012/compare-the-evolution-of-a-binary-variable-between-two-groups-of-a-panel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595012/compare-the-evolution-of-a-binary-variable-between-two-groups-of-a-panel)